# In windows 7,how to simultaneous update multiple virtue machines' chrome version via cmd

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I want to do some automated testing in Chrome using multiple virtue machines and chrome's version is an important factor to performance.So I hope I can control the version of chrome and I want to keep all machines' chrome is in the same version. How can I disabled the automatic update of Chrome? Besides, when I want to update chrome in different machines,I hope I can update them in one machine by cmd instead of updating them one by one by manual.
I tried the command ,it seems useless.
sc \vm1.... start gupdate
sc \vm2.... start gupdate
Any suggestions ? Thank you.

Comment: corporate network prevent me to use "boxStarter".Can I just remote update Chrome via cmd or power shell? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the operating system used on your VM's, but I would look at using BoxStarter for this. In particular, see the section in the docs about [Remote Installations](http://boxstarter.org/InstallingPackages#RemoteInstallations)

Basically you would create a BoxStarter package (a simple PowerShell script) and then push it to the list of VMs. The package will include the registry updates for:

- "AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes"
- "Update policy override default"

Comment: Thanks a lot.I will try it. and the operating system is windows 7. : )

Comment: It's a pity that the corporate network prevented me to download "Boxstarter"

Comment: You could try standard  ps remoting http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/ . Do you control the VMs? Are they already deployed or do you create them?

Comment: I already deployed them ,and i can control them via "VMware vSphere Client"

Comment: It looks like you should expore VMware PowerCLI as it will allow you to copy scripts (e.g. batch files) and invoke them remotely. See: http://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2012/06/be-efficient-virtualize-automate-your-test-environment.html